# Typescript/Vue - How can I get access to the vuex store when I'm declaring a default object for a prop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

In my Vue-Typescript project I have declared a prop named "data" and for this prop I want also define an object structure as default. Some fields are multilingual and for that purpose I need access to the vuex store that will return all active languages that the user has activated. This allows me to generate the fields dynamically. Does anyone have an idea how can I achieve this?

```js
export default class CompanyForm extends Vue {

    public dialog = false;

    @Prop({default: {
        name: '',
        address: this.$store.state.Language.data.getLanguageDataStructure(),
        telephone: '',
        fax: '',
        email: '',
        website: ''
    }})
    data: object;
});
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. So assuming, you pass through that object to the component. Why dont you rather set that whole object inside the store state. Let the component access the state member. It would be much cleaner?

Comment: @JeremyWalters The object that you can see here is the component. I just didn't paste the HTML code that belong to it. When I'm defining the default attributes inside the store state, I have to split the component validation, attributes etc. from the default attributes which don't seem to be a nice solution, because the state itself must be declared inside the component to be independent on every initialization

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to manually import the store and use it instead of `this.$store`, since the component will not be instanciated yet when the default for the prop is calculated.

> Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available inside default or validator functions.

(see [Vue Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks), scroll up a little to see the warning)

You should also use a function as default if your default value is an object or an array, because otherwise all your instances will share the same default value.
(see [Vue Prop Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks), the `propE` example)

Something like this should work:

```js
import store from 'path/to/your/store';

export default class CompanyForm extends Vue {

    public dialog = false;

    @Prop({default: () => ({
        name: '',
        address: store.state.Language.data.getLanguageDataStructure(),
        telephone: '',
        fax: '',
        email: '',
        website: ''
    })})
    data: object;
});
```

Comment: Okay that make sense to me that this solution will work. Apparently I forgot that it is also possible to import the store directly. ^^ 
I'm gonna try this solution in the evening. Thanks for the hint with the function as default, didn't know that it would behave like this.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ProV Yeah the vue documentation does not point out those edge cases very well :) Sorry if the typescript is not 100% correct, it's been quite a while since i last used it ;)

Comment: No problem, I still understood the implementation ^^